# Ошибка при импорте flask-login

Tags: python, flask

При импорте flask-login

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskblog\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskblog\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .login_manager import LoginManager
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskblog\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .utils import _create_identifier
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskblog\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from werkzeug.urls import url_decode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls' (C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskblog\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\urls.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Читал похожую ситуацию где была ошибка с 'url_encode' там советовали установить старую версию werkzeug==0.16.0, но с его установкой приходится ставить старые версии flask и flask-login и даже после этого ошибки продолжают сыпаться, в чем проблема и можно ли пользоваться этими модуялми на последних версиях?

Comment: Ну а версии flask_login и самого́ Flask какие хоть?

Comment: @andreymal Flask==3.0.0, flask-login==0.6.2

Comment: Откатитесь на Flask 2.3 или ждите новую версию flask_login

Comment: @andreymal помог откат до версии 2.2, спасибо